# MVC open view from another function

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to open view (ActionResult) from another function?

something like:

```
public ActionResult AAA(){

return View();

}

public void BBB(){

//Fire the AAA ActionResult??
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the function and not return the value. The question is Why? What are you trying to accomplish that could be done another way? Why would you want to throw away the View with a Void method?

```
public ActionResult AAA()
{
     return View();
}

public void BBB()
{
     AAA();
}
```

Comment: I was thinking to have some condition logic in the void function with corresponding ActionResults to display, i.e. if(IsAAA) show ActionResult AAA, else if (IsCCC) show ActionResult CCC... something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This way only I guess:

```
public ActionResult AAA(){
   return View();
}

public ActionResult BBB(){
   return RedirectToAction("AAA");
}
```

Comment: thanks i am familiar with RedirectToAction, but that's not what I need

Comment: If so - the ansrwer is NO. It is not possible.